# Serializer field named incorrectly

Tags: python, django, django-views

I'm attempting to present some serialized data, and am getting a  AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `name`.

models.py:

```
class Resource(models.Model):
    """Initial representation of a resource."""
    # ID from fixture resources, for internal dedupe
    internal_id = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True, blank=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    categories = models.ManyToManyField("Category")
    neighborhoods = models.ManyToManyField("Neighborhood")
    email_contact = models.EmailField(null=True, blank=True)
    pdf = models.ManyToManyField("PDF")
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    website = models.URLField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)

    # address
    street_address = models.CharField(max_length=400, null=True, blank=True)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=True, blank=True)
    latitude = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)
    longitude = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)
    zip_code = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=True, blank=True)

    # meta
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    modified_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'{}'.format(self.name)

    @property
    def categories_str(self):
        return [str(t) for t in self.categories.all()]

    @property
    def neighborhoods_str(self):
        return [str(t) for t in self.neighborhoods.all() if t] or ["Houston"]

    @property
    def bookmark(self):
        """This is here to make it easier to serialize a standard resource."""
        return getattr(self, "_bookmark", None)

    @bookmark.setter
    def bookmark(self, bookmark):
        self._bookmark = bookmark

    def indexing(self):
        safe_zip = str(self.zip_code or "")
        safe_neighborhood = [n for n in self.neighborhoods.all() if n] or ["Houston"]
        obj = ResourceDoc(
            meta={"id": self.id},
            name=self.name,
            resource_suggest=self.name,
            email_contact=self.email_contact,
            phone=self.phone,
            description=self.description,
            website=self.website,
            categories=self.categories_str,
            street_address=self.street_address,
            city=self.city,
            state=self.state,
            zip_code=safe_zip,
            neighborhoods=self.neighborhoods_str,
            # TODO default to Houston for now but need a way to handle case where we don't know neighborhood or zip code
            location_suggest=[str(attr) for attr in chain([safe_zip], safe_neighborhood) if attr],
            created_at=self.created_at,
            modified_at=self.modified_at,
        )
        if self.latitude and self.longitude:
            obj.geo_coords = {
                "lat": str(self.latitude),
                "lon": str(self.longitude),
            }
        obj.save(index="welnity_production_2")
        return obj.to_dict(include_meta=True)
```

serializers.py:

```
class ResourceSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
bookmark = BookmarkMetaSerializer(read_only=True)
notes = PrivateNoteSerializer(read_only=True, many=True)
categories = CategorySerializer(read_only=True, many=True)
neighborhoods = NeighborhoodSerializer(read_only=True, many=True)
class Meta:
    model = Resource
    fields = '__all__'
```

view.py:

```
class BookmarkGroupView(View):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        # resources = Resource.objects.filter(bookmarks__user=request.user)
        # resources = get_enriched_resources(request.user, resources)

        group = BookmarkGroup.objects.get(name='food')
        resources = group.bookmarks.all()
        serialized = ResourceSerializer(resources, many=True)
        context = {
            "component": "groups.js",
            "props": {
                "resources": JSONRenderer().render(serialized.data)
            }
        }
        return render(request, "groups.html", context)
```

the error is

```
Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `name` on serializer `ResourceSerializer`.
The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `Bookmark` instance.
Original exception text was: 'Bookmark' object has no attribute 'name'.
```

any help or direction would be much appreciated!

Comment: show the code of your `BookmarkMetaSerializer`

Comment: Show your `models.py` also

Comment: @JerinPeterGeorge

`class Bookmark(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    resource = models.ForeignKey("Resource", on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="bookmarks")
    # meta
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    modified_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('user', 'resource',)
        ordering = ('resource',)

    def __str__(self):
        return "{} | {}".format(self.user, self.resource)

`

Comment: @BearBrown 

code:

`class BookmarkMetaSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Bookmark
        fields = '__all__'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are giving your ResourceSerializer the wrong model instances.

```
    resources = group.bookmarks.all()
    serialized = ResourceSerializer(resources, many=True)
```

Here you are telling your serializer to use `group.bookmarks.all()` as data source which are instances of `Bookmark`, not `Resource`.

Comment: I see what you're getting at. How would I access the resource from the queryset?

Comment: You can do it with for example `Resource.objects.filter(bookmark__in=group.bookmarks.all())` but i dont know enough about your data model to say the most efficient way.

Comment: Thanks! Makes so much sense now!